# php and smarty var. value

Tags: php, smarty

```
smarty file
{php}
some php code...

    $php_var = "{/php}{$smarty_var}{php}";
    echo $php_var;

some php code ...
{/php}
smarty file
```

Why '$php_var' value is: ?>

How get $smarty_var value?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you putting smarty tags within {php}? Just do {php}// the code{/php}{$smarty_var}{php}// the code {/php}

Comment: I need get smarty variable and work with this variable in php.
Echo I use just a test sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `$php_var` is wrong is because you accidentally closed your `{php}` when you put a `{/php}` in the PHP code there.  Smarty doesn't understand enough to care that it's in a quoted string.

To actually get the smarty variable, use `$this->get_template_vars('smarty_var')` somewhere in your '{php}' block.

Alternately, split the template into two smaller ones invoked in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening and closing {php} tags. You could try,

```
{php}
$php_var = $this->get_template_vars('your_smarty_var_name');
echo $php_var;
{/php}
```